# How can i print a list without the brackets?

Tags: python, python-2.7

This is a function that allows me to print my two lists, `cursosArreglo` and `tareasArreglo`, but when I print them they come out like this: `[['qwert'], ['fisica']]`
Esta es la lista de tareas y sus prioridades:

`[['zxcvb'], ['4'], ['nbvcx'], ['3'], ['tregd'], ['2'], ['bvxx'], ['3']]`

how can i print both lists without the brackets?

```
def verTareas():
    print("")
    print("Saludos "+nombre+(" a continuacion puede ver su informacion"))
    print("")
    print("Esta es la lista de cursos asignados: ")
    print str(cursosArreglo)
    print("Esta es la lista de tareas y sus prioridades: ")
    print '\n'+str(tareasArreglo)
    print("")
    regresar()
```

Comment: See [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html); possibly use in conjunction with a generator expression or flat map here.

Comment: @user2864740 I tried that, but I got the following error: descriptor 'join' requires a 'str' object but received a 'list'

Comment: @luispe str.join works in a sequence of str[ings], you have a sequence of lists. First convert it to a sequence of strings. (I think that the code that creates the list may be accidentally creating the inner lists of one element - they don't appear useful, so perhaps remove them at the source?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's some code that works without any modules or anything.

```
for i in range(len(cursosArreglo)):
    cursosArreglo[i] = "".join(cursosArreglo[i])

print(", ".join(cursosArreglo))
```

You can also run this for `tareasArreglo` by substituting it in for `cursosArreglo`.

This first goes through your list of lists, then substitutes each spot in the list with a string version of it, by using [`str.join()`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_join.htm), then `str.join` again to fully join the list.

**This can also be compressed into one line.**

```
strCursosArreglo = ", ".join("".join(i) for i in cursosArreglo)
```

Comment: Could this be further reduced by iterating over the string `cursosArreglo`  itself instead of its length? By this I mean `for i in cursosArreglo` instead of `for i in range(len(cursosArreglo))`.

Comment: @Matthew0898 It could, but then you would have to use `.index`. I prefer it like this

Comment: Or you can use enumerate(), `for i, s in enumerate(cursosArreglo):` though I don't see why you would assign back into the list. You can definitely iterate over list without an index in the comprehension (generator is better) `", ".join("".join(s) for s in cursosArreglo)`

Comment: @achampion That is a very good idea. Would this be considered list comprehension or a generator expression?

Comment: removing the `[]` makes it a generator, i.e. it doesn't populate a whole list and delays execution until needed.

Answer (score 6):

For a list of lists, `lst` just use `join` with a suitable delimiter, after flattening it. You can use `chain` of the `itertools` module to flatten the list:

```
from itertools import chain

lst = [['zxcvb'], ['4'], ['nbvcx'], ['3'], ['tregd'], ['2'], ['bvxx'], ['3']]
flat_lst =  list(chain.from_iterable(lst))
print ','.join(flat_lst)
```

Answer (score 2):

You also use `lambda`, the below code:

```
>>> func= lambda lst: [m for i in lst for m in func(i)] if type(lst) is list else [lst]
>>> lst = [['zxcvb'], ['4'], ['nbvcx'], ['3'], ['tregd'], ['2'], ['bvxx'], ['3']]
>>> func(lst)
['zxcvb', '4', 'nbvcx', '3', 'tregd', '2', 'bvxx', '3']
```

Or,

```
>>> func=lambda L: sum(map(func, L), []) if isinstance(L, list) else [L]
>>> func(lst)
['zxcvb', '4', 'nbvcx', '3', 'tregd', '2', 'bvxx', '3']
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to flatten the list and then join it, e.g. using nested `join`s:

```
>>> data = [['zxcvb'], ['4'], ['nbvcx'], ['3'], ['tregd'], ['2'], ['bvxx'], ['3']]
>>> print ", ".join("".join(s) for s in data)
zxcvb, 4, nbvcx, 3, tregd, 2, bvxx, 3
```